# Match the values in google sheets from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need for my two data sets to find exact match.

In sheet called set1 I need for it to look up results of set2 and if set1 sheet has a match with set2 sheet then print Match, otherwise no match.

Below is what I tried:

=INDEX(A:A,MATCH,set2!A:A)

Comment: read about the parameters for MATCH() and INDEX() here.https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: What have you tried so far? A copy of the sheet you're using would be helpful. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

use in row 1:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; set2!A2:A); "Match"; )
```